# Using the Facebook login button code for another application

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPhone programming, and what I want to do is duplicate the same concept as the facebook login button.  I've generated a navigation item that I named 'Account' so that when it is clicked on it displays four buttons exactly like the Facebook application on the iPhone, showing "connection", "setting", "help" and "cancel".

How might I do this?

Comment: you can't create the interface  same as Facebook

Comment: or something similar to that, would be great !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FB-lib for IPhone Three20 ( https://github.com/facebook/three20 ).
1. Read about the lib.
2. Download it, and refer it to your application.
3. Use all posible tool, what You want (In your case its "TTBUTTON" class).